# App Service Editor in Azure

Tags: azure

The App Service Editor (Preview) in Azure

When I 'Initialize Git Repository', where is my git repository created? Is there a repository URL that I can use?

And if later, after finish changing my code, I want to export repository (e.g., get a copy to my local machine), how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can access the git repository through command line or via the URL given in your instance dashboard in **properties**

[image]

there should be a Git URL field there.